# Change the identity an assembly runs under

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication, iis-7.5

I have an assembly which I call from within my asp.net web site.

I want the assembly to run under a different user than the -windows authenticated - main site runs under.

The reason is, the assembly needs admin permissions - but I don't want the whole website/IIS to be running as an administrator.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance,

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My guess would be that the assembly would have to run in another process in order to use different credentials.**

Here's an example of how to kick off another process in .net
http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ProcessStart.aspx

Then that process could run under whatever permission required.

If that's the case you will have to coordinate the interaction between your website and the other process.

This would most likely be done using [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that,you need to use the impersonation mechanism. 
You can find tones of resources on Stack Overflow and MSDN using keywords asp.net impersonation.

Where will be located this assembly you'll have to run with a different account?
Will it be loaded within your existing AppDomain of you Asp.Net app?

Cheers!